# my jax-rs server limited my response

Tags: jax-rs, cxf

I have a cxf jax-rs server. My responses are json. Some of my responses are a little large (more than 1MB). when I have large responses(more than 60kB) my server only transmit 32kB of response. I want to know if jax-rs server has a maximum size for json responses. I want to increase this limit.

Comment: There should be no size limit. How are you managing the responses?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @pedrofb. I use "return Response.ok().entity(response).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JS‌​ON).build();" to return response. my response is a String. in past my server doesn't have this problem. can my free memory affect this? By ignoring buffers and cached memory server has 5GB free memory, but by considering buffers and cached memory server has only 700MB free memory.

Comment: I think no. The JAX-RS framework should not limit the response. May be is your client. Could you check your server with Postman? If it not works, check the params of your http server

Comment: Thanks for your help @pedrofb. With Postman I recieved response imcomplete too. When I checked response of my server in server system with tshark, server sended complete answer. After check I see that my server system don't have any disk space, so nginx between my server and client couldn't send the complete response. by adding free space of disk, my server is working currectly now.